# Merge repository into a folder of an other repository

Tags: git, merge, repository

I want to merge a repository into a folder of an other repository.

Currently, it looks like this :

I have multiple repositories like A, B, C,..

```
-> A 
   .git
-> B
   .git
-> C
   .git
```

And then I have only one repository for example called R which contains folder A,B,C (which are not git repositories but only folder which contains almost the same stuff than the previous A,B,C git repositories) :

```
-> R
   .git
   A
   B
   C
```

I want to merge A repository with the A folder in R repository, B repository with the B folder in R repository, etc.

What would be the best solution ?

Comment: I haven't found a good way of doing this. You can always add "A", "B" and "C" as remotes in "R" and e.g. `git merge A/<branch> --allow-unrelated-histories` but this would put files from "A" in the root of the application and not in folder "A" (going by your layout) which you could then move. The same goes for `git cherry-pick A/<branch>`.  If you were to restructure "A" to have an "A" folder, then you would succeed in getting the files from repo A into folder A.

Comment: Look up [[git] subtree merge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+subtree+merge).

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739895/is-it-possible-to-push-on-git-when-i-only-have-a-subdirectory-of-the-project-on/57740405#57740405) an answer that's not close enough to mark as a dup bot should be enough to set you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks @zrrbite , found some stuff interesting there.

Comment: thanks @jthill found some interesting stuff too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of the `tree`s in a git repository for a branch determine the resulting merge. I don't believe you can say "merge this branch from this remote, but merge it into this folder", since that would require git to re-interpret all the `tree` objects.

I'm not sure what you are allowed to do with your repos A, B and C, but if i restructure repo A to have an "A" folder to mimic "R", i can e.g. `git merge repoA/master --merge-unrelated-histories` after adding `repoA` as a remote.

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/repotest (master)
$ git fetch repoA
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
From D:/dev/git/repotest_A
   b73c55c..0b2748b  master     -> repoA/master

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/repotest (master)
$ git merge repoA/master --allow-unrelated-histories
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 A/file_from_A.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A/file_from_A.txt

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/repotest/A (master)
$ ls
file_from_folder_A.txt  file_from_repo_A.txt
```

If i had files with identical names e.g. `file_from_folder_A.txt` then i would simply get a merge-conflict to solve:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/repotest (master)             
$ git merge repoA/master --allow-unrelated-histories             
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in A/file_from_folder_A.txt               
Auto-merging A/file_from_folder_A.txt                                        
Recorded preimage for 'A/file_from_folder_A.txt'                             
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
                                                             
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/repotest (master|MERGING)
...
```

Comment: I succeeded in what I wanted to do. Thanks for your help!